# Bootstrap 4 Mosaic Layout

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I'm really struggling with implementing a mosaic-style layout. I have tried using Bootstrap 4's grid system, flex, and various other methods but I don't seem to have the knowledge to implement a solution that works well enough on all devices.

I have attached an image of the layout, the middle two boxes are for text content and the rest are images, all of which need to play nice on all devices.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to align images in a mosaic style? html/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22334923/how-to-align-images-in-a-mosaic-style-html-css)

Comment: This article shows a few ways involving Multi-Column layout and Flexbox. Take a look: https://codeburst.io/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: area1;
}

.item4 {
  height: 100px;
}


.item5 {
  grid-area: area5;
}


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'area1 . .'
    'area1 area4 area5'
    'area1 . area5'
    '. . area5';
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: #323232;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>  
  <div class="item4"></div>
  <div class="item5"></div>
  <div class="item6"></div>
  <div class="item7"></div>
  <div class="item8"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried bootstrap `.card-columns`? (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns). I have used this solution in the past for a mosaic layout using bootstrap 4.